# Return polymorphic type without dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, return-value

Is there a standard design pattern with which I can return a polymorphic type from a procedure without also being required to dynamically allocate memory for the object within the procedure?

Or do polymorphism and dynamic memory allocation necessarily go hand-in-hand in practice?

I'm hoping for a C++03-compatible solution, but if there is a C++11 one then I'm interested in seeing that as well.

Comment: You need to be more specific. If you know exactly the type, you can just return it by value. If you return a pointer, it doesn't necessarily have to be to a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Who's "you" in your question? The procedure knows the dynamic type (think: overridden by derived classes), but obviously the caller doesn't (it's not in the function signature), otherwise polymorphism would be pointless.

Comment: You're you. So are you returning by value or what?

Comment: Ok, deleted. I don't think you have any other option of constructing the object at runtime.

Comment: *"with which I can return a polymorphic type from a procedure"* I think this is not specific enough. Consider `base* procedure() { static derived d; return &d; }` The *dynamic memory allocation* part to me suggests that you think of *creating* objects within the procedure, and need to pass them to the caller.

Comment: @dyp: Yeah, I'm constructing the object in the procedure, but I want to give the caller access to it. I just need to find a decent way to construct it in a space that the caller has access to, without the performance penalty of forcing the caller to use heap memory. (e.g. a design pattern for providing a stack-based buffer allocated by the caller)

Comment: @dyp this is basically similar to my now deleted answer, you basically say what the object should be at compile time. I think OP doesn't want this.

Comment: IMO, you should separate the concerns of *creation* and *allocation*. The *creation* function should simply create a new object in a buffer provided by the caller. This enables the caller to use any memory allocation scheme they like - fixed-size buffers, `new`, fancy allocators, ..

Comment: *"procedure knows the dynamic type"* does it always return the same type?

Comment: @dyp: The question is *how*? How should the caller know how much memory to allocate, and how/where should the caller allocate the memory?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Yeah. The signature is fixed (it's defined in the base class), whereas the implementation is flexible (it's defined in the derived class).

Comment: How to take a buffer as a function parameter and construct an object on it?

Comment: Well, the good ol' `void*` and a `size_t` parameters, possibly combined into a single parameter of class type. Or use the existing allocator "interface".

Comment: An overridden function can change the return type to a derived return type. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Comment: Be careful of alignment if you go down that route. I would consider an object pool.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Yeah, alignment was one of the reasons I asked this question... how would I make an object pool work for this, though?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question clearly specifying your situation and concerns. I have never used an object pool myself; I only know they are possible.

Comment: @dyp: You can't just blindly take in a buffer, you have to make sure it's aligned and sized properly. How should the caller know this? Don't forget I'm asking for a design principle here, the question isn't how to pass around pointers...

Comment: @NeilKirk: If I make another question asking for object pools then I will be incurring an XY problem; i.e. someone will complain that an object pool isn't the solution to my actual problem (and I'm not sure it is, either). That's why I asked the underlying question instead.

Comment: The alignment issue can be simplified by using the constraints for allocation functions: The buffer shall be suitably aligned for any object that is at most the passed size large. To let the caller know the minimum size, you can use any of the techniques where either the creation function is called twice, or a related function tells the caller the minimum size. The allocator interface inverts the roles: the creation functions *requests* from the allocator a certain amount of suitably-aligned space.

Comment: @dyp: The allocator pattern doesn't solve anything; it just makes things more complicated. Where would the allocator get the space from, if not the dynamic heap? Same problem with the double-call technique.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is for the caller to use `_alloca`, but that's neither portable nor can I think of a nice way of abstracting it away inside a separate class.

Comment: An allocator does not have to call `new` to allocate memory for each object. It can use an existing "allocation", e.g. an existing buffer created via `new` or a local buffer "on the stack" or even a global/thread-local buffer. All of them typically impose tighter restrictions on the size of the (derived) object than `new` does.

Comment: @dyp that's exactly why I'm saying it doesn't solve the problem -- the problem is precisely that the caller doesn't know how much space to allocate for the object or with what alignment, and an allocator doesn't get rid of this problem.

Comment: Since the allocator is provided by the client, I'd argue that the client *does* know how much space to allocate. They just don't know that *prior to calling the creation function*. And they conceptually cannot know this (unless there's a separate function or call to let them know the size). -- There's always a size restriction for objects. You could simply make it explicit: the creation function could guarantee that the derived type will not get larger than X byte. (If it does, you can still resort to `new`)

Answer (score 0):

[Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)

Really this is for performance, to reduce allocations; it seems applicable in your scenario however, assuming you have a limit on the number of instances of an object. Code below illustrates the idea. This requires a priori knowledge of what types are involved (as you need to allocate the necessary object buffers). Also deleting (returning the type to the pool) requires care and knowledge of the type. This can be done via virtual function call.

```
template< typename Type >
struct TypePool
{
    static TypePool& GetInstance(){ return pool; }

    Type& GetPooledObject() 
    {
        return arr[0]; // do some real tracking here
    }

  private:
    static TypePool< Type > pool;
    Type arr[10];
};

struct A{ };
struct B : public A { };
struct C : public A { };

// The catch to this design...
TypePool<A> TypePool<A>::pool;
TypePool<B> TypePool<B>::pool;
TypePool<C> TypePool<C>::pool;

struct ObjectFactory
{
    // Actual function you would call to construct the object
    // ObjectFactory::GetType< A > or GetType< B >
    template< typename Type >
    static A& GetType()
    {
        return TypePool<A>::GetInstance().GetPooledObject();
    }
};


int main( int argc, char* r[] )
{
    A& object = ObjectFactory::GetType< C >();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require the caller to pass down a pointer to the object pool of the correct type to the called? Or are you saying I need thread local storage (C++11-only)? Because storing a pointer to the pool inside every object is undesirable...

Comment: The pool is static (for each type, look at the member `static TypePool pool`) so at compile-time it is determined which pool to use. Every type can then refer to its own pool very easily via `TypePool< MyType >::GetInstance` and so return itself.

Comment: An object pool is one of the few places I would be ok with a singleton.

Comment: If I make it a global Singleton then I have to lock the pool when accessing it from multiple threads, effectively serializing them. So I need to make it thread-local.

Comment: It wasn't clear in your question that this has to work in a multi-threaded environment. Yes. if it is threaded you need to done one of the following: (A) lock it, (B) thread local storage, (C) create as many pools as threads and use thread id to simultaneously perform pooling in the same static object.